How to trigger Slack APP refresh of cache as Slack APP is caching API responses
We're encountering an issue where we have a slack app integration in a slack channel that sends an api call to our API.
This API is hosted on AWS Beanstalk and we regularly update this API. Now what we are experiencing is that even though we're updating this API, the api calls that are being sent through slack seem to be hitting an old instance of this API.
For example we make a change in a route that is being accessed by a post call through slack, and its executing code that is actually no longer in that production API.
To give an example, we have a util function in our API that returns a hardcoded value that's not in the DB. value was set to 100000 6 months ago, even though we now have set that value to 250000 2 months ago this is not being reflected in our API calls. Any interaction through the slack app will read 100000 which is an old value...
This is causing issues because the API calls are now hitting a sort of cached API which is months old we now notice... We tried reinstalling the Slack APP (Settings -> Install APP -> Reinstall to workspace) but that doesnt seem to do the trick.. It's still accessing the same api call but a previous version you could say...
We're out of ideas on how to resolve this, anything we change in that API call doesnt get reflected through the slack app, as it seems to be hitting a cached instance of our API? Is this even possible?
Any solution would really be appreciated.
Thank you!
We tried reinstalling the Slack APP (Settings -> Install APP -> Reinstall to workspace)
We pushed multiple updates to our API, over the past few months but no refresh or updated values.
